# installing aptana on a computer with no Internet

Tags: javascript, aptana

I am trying to install aptana on a computer that is not connected to the Internet during install it is trying to download prerequisite software i wish it will tell what it is looking for I have the latest java installed I have git installed what else is it looking for ? Any help would be appreciated. my system is windows 7 64 bit

Comment: I just downloaded this package and I am sure what this is there is no install or setup files in this package it does not look like a standalone version looks more like a plug for eclipse

Comment: Standalone does mean that the package is self contained I assume it means it is not an eclipse plugin so at this point I am done trying to get this thing to work I my option the install package assumes to much and I am deleting this and eclipse and will find another ide that I can use with my course

Answer (score 0):

try installing Standalone version for Aptana 3.
Aptana 3 studio is compatible with x64 architecture (64 bit version of windows)
http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is NodeJS. For Aptana Studio to be installed without downloading anything from the internet, you need latest Java, GIT, and NodeJS.

Comment: and here is a direct link http://go.aptana.com/installer_nodejs_windows