# Install Aptana Studio on windows

Tags: aptana

When I try to install Aptana Studio, I get an error message  Failed to correctly acquire installer_nodejs_windows.msi file: CRC error.  I am then told that Aptana Studio setup ended prematurely bacause of an error. The installer then shuts down without installing the application.  I have installed nodejs, but still get this error.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the PC you are installing it on, has no internet connection.

I had following message boxes  before I got the error you mentioned:

[image: go.appcelerator.com/installer_nodejs_windows.msi]
[image: go.appcelerator.com/installer_git_windows.exe]

**Solution:** On a PC connected to internet either go to the URLs above , download and transfer the installer files to your PC, or get the newest versions of nodejs and git, then install them on your development PC.

*See also:*

- [installing aptana on a computer with no Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069702/installing-aptana-on-a-computer-with-no-internet)
- [Cannot install Aptana Studio 3.6 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514458/cannot-install-aptana-studio-3-6-on-windows/31284272#31284272)

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error when trying to install Aptana 3.6.1 just now. Found the solution in this thread [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514458/cannot-install-aptana-studio-3-6-on-windows)(run the installer with "/passive /norestart").